# No puedo guardar archivo desde mi aplicación, me da error "open failed eperm (operation not permitted)"

Tags: android, android-manifest

Estoy intentando guardar un archivo .html desde mi aplicación Android y no me está funcionando.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/17_02_2022_04_30_54.html: open failed: EPERM
> (Operation not permitted)

El cual es capturado en esta línea del código:

```
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
```

No sé si es problema del *emulador*, pues creo tener todos los permisos necesarios en `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

Y en `application`:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ... etc
</application>
```

Este es el código completo para guardar el archivo:

```
private void saveHtmlFile(String html) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String fileName = DateFormat.format("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
    fileName = fileName + ".html";
    File file = new File(path, fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = html.getBytes();
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Save : " + file.getPath());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que ya no se pueden leer o crear archivos fuera de la estructura de la aplicación. Anteriormente podías crear una archivo o directorio fuera, como en este ejemplo:

```
/storage/emulated/0/17_02_2022_04_30_54.html
```

pero **ahora se debe usar [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))** en lugar de [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())

```
 //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
 String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

y tu archivo se creara dentro del directorio `/files` que se encuentra dentro de la estructura de directorios de la aplicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/
```

dentro de este directorio es donde se tienen que crear y leer los archivos. Es un cambio realizado por cuestiones de seguridad en los dispositivos android.