# Escribir en un fichero de la carpeta raw

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero escribir un fichero txt que está en la carpeta raw en mi programa de Android Studio y no me escribe pero no me saca ningún error tampoco. Tengo este código:

```
    Date date = new Date(calendar.getDate());
    Dia nuevo=new Dia(date,huerto,sulfatos.getText().toString(),plazo.getText().toString(),planta.getText().toString());
    MainActivity.listaDia.add(nuevo);

    String linea = nuevo.getDia()+","+nuevo.getHuerta()+","+nuevo.getSulfato()+","+nuevo.getPlazoSeg()+","+nuevo.getPlanta();

    try {

        OutputStreamWriter miItem = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("dias.txt",Context.MODE_APPEND));

        miItem.write(linea+ "\n");

        miItem.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres pero no veo que le estes diciendo, por lo menos en tu código, la ubicación del fichero "dias.txt". ¿Cuándo y dónde se lo asignas?

Answer (score 0):

En este caso la opción es usar `getFilesDir()` para guardar tu archivo en almacenamiento interno:

[Como guardar un archivo en la Memoria Interna Fisica en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316590/como-guardar-un-archivo-en-la-memoria-interna-fisica-en-android)

[No puedo guardar o encontrar archivo en el almacenamiento local (local storage) de mi aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136709/no-puedo-guardar-o-encontrar-archivo-en-el-almacenamiento-local-local-storage)

o usar `getExternalFilesDir()` para guardar tu archivo en almacenamiento externo:

[Consulta para guardar archivos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428106/consulta-para-guardar-archivos)

[No puedo guardar archivo desde mi aplicación, me da error "open failed eperm (operation not permitted)"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/515542/)

ya que **no es posible escribir dentro del directorio `/raw` de tu proyecto Android ya que este directorio es únicamente de "solo lectura".**